# Pegar os dados dentro de um resultado json_decode

Tags: php

Como eu faria para pegar o valor da string login e senha dentro de um json_decode? O que acontece é que quando trago o resultado de um curl:

```
$obj = json_decode($output);
```

Aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Seus dados de acesso é: login: xxxxx e senha: YYYY

Tentei pegar o login da seguinte forma:

```
list($mensagem,$login) = explode("login:",$obj->info->cidade[0]->dados[0]->mensagem);
```

Mas ele retorna:

> xxxxx e senha: YYYY

Precisaria pegar somente o XXXXX para o login e YYYY para a senha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível resolver esse problema com uma regex `: \w+` que captura `:` seguido de um espaço e um ou mais caracteres(`a-z0-9_`).

Para acessar o login e senha use: `$m[0][1]` e  `$m[0][2]`, `$m[0][0]` pode ser descartado pois é a string `login`.

```
$str = 'Seus dados de acesso é: login: xxxxx e senha: YYYY';

preg_match_all('/: \w+/i', $str, $m);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($m);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => : login
            [1] => : xxxxx
            [2] => : YYYY
        )

)
```

Comment: Perfeito rray. Só mais uma dúvida. O login e senha por algumas vezes pode também contém números. Ex.: login: 2016_y1e3 e senha: 1a3r. Como ficaria o regex? Desculpe a pergunta, pois não conheço muito regex.

Comment: @Fox.11 editada a resposta, veja se é isso.

Comment: Funcionou!! Obrigado pela ajuda rray.